# Missing script section in mhtml after calling saveWebArchive

Tags: android, android-webview, android-4.4-kitkat

I am developing an Android app containing webview.

After Kitkat, Android 4.4, WebView is powered by Chrome, and the web content will be saved as MHTML by calling **saveWebArchive**.

However, I found that all the javascript code in "<*script*>...<*/script*>" are missing in the MHTML file.

Take w3schools.com for instance.

```
webView.loadUrl("http://www.w3schools.com");
...
webView.saveWebArchive(filename);
```

If you compare the MHTML file with the source code, you will find that all the javascript function under script section are missing.

How can I saved the entire html file with all the js function?